# gitLab - not able to push local branches to remote

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a developer access right provided for gitlab. I am not able to perform any kind of "push" operation to remote origin. Whether creating new local branch and trying pushing it or making changes to existing local branch and pushing it. Any suggestions or insights ?

Below is the error message I get immediately after I do push:

```
remote: git: /softwares/gitlab-5.2.1-0/common/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by git)        

remote: /softwares/gitlab-7.3.2-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.7.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:222: warning: Insecure world writable dir /opt in PATH, mode 040777        
remote: GitLab: You are not allowed to access some of the refs!        
Pushing to http://10.200.10.66:90/yes/someservice.git
To http://10.200.10.66:90/yes/someservice.git
 ! [remote rejected] some_branch -> some_branch(pre-receive hook declined)



error: failed to push some refs to 'http://10.200.10.66:90/yes/someservice.git'

Completed with errors, see above.
```

Comment: Not a solution to your problem, but I recommend to take the warning `Insecure world writable dir /opt in PATH, mode 040777` seriously.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you try to push a protected branch.

If you are project owner, check the "Protected Branches" (current Gitlab version has it in the settings menu top right).

**EDIT:** In the current Gitlab version, the protected branches look like this:
[image: gitlab screenshot]

Just unprotect `some_branch` or change who is allowed to push.

Comment: Thanks @das_j, but we don't have protected branches for the repository I am working on gitLab. So, there might be something else other than what you mentioned. Could you think of anything else that might be causing this issue ?

Comment: @Chuchoo Are you allowed to push any other branch?

Comment: Nope I am not allowed to push anything from my local to remote. I get the same error message.

Comment: Can your run `gitlab-rake gitlab:check` to check if there is anything wrong with your GitLab?

Comment: Hey @das_j, where exactly should I enter that command? Do you have place in gitLab to enter it?

Comment: Dpeends. Have you installed gitlab with omnibus or from source?

Comment: I installed it through source. Interesting thing is, I am able to push my local changes/branch to other remote repos but not able to on only that one repo. Very weird.